# AzureXplorer - local blob storage - unexpected hidden fies when manually creating folders

Tags: c, azure, blob, local, hidden

AzureXplorer - local blob storage - unexpected hidden fies when manually creating folders

Our C# ListBlobs method that works OK up in Azure revealed one extra file per folder locally named "$$$.$$$" that are not visible in AzureXplorer or ClumsyLeaf.  Neither Google nor MSDN  has turned up any note of this so I was wondering if any one else has seen this. The workaround for this defect in AzureXplorer is to manually create local blob folders with ClumsyLeaf which does NOT produce these hidden files allowing us to continue testing locally without specifically coding around these files.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Blob Storage **does not support folders**. All and any software that fakes folders creates files (blobs). Folders (or directories) are simulated by setting prefixes in the blob names. Because the slash character is valid one for blob name.

You can find more information about blob service in the following resources:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179376.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx

From the second resource:

> The Blob service is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical
>   scheme. However, you may specify a character or string delimiter
>   within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy.

That is why, in order to have a "folder" you must have at least one blob (file) within that "folder" (I quote the word "folder", because it is not real one, but just part of the name of the blob itself).

Comment: I appreciate the clarification!